# Test is returning param missing or value empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

I am working on a small application in RoR 4 and am running into a hiccup. Here is the code I am working with:

```
def update
  @status = current_user.statuses.find(params[:id])

  if params[:status] && params[:status].has_key?(:user_id)
    params[:status].delete(:user_id)
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    if @status.update(status_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @status, notice: 'Status was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @status } #Original
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @status.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private
  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def status_params
    params.require(:status).permit(:user_id, :content)
  end
end
```

And here is the test I am running:

```
test "should not update status if nothing has changed" do
  sign_in users(:sean)
  patch :update, id: @status
  assert_redirected_to status_path(assigns(:status))
  assert_equal assigns(:status).user_id, users(:sean).id
end
```

When I run the test, this is the failure I am getting:

```
1) Error:
   StatusesControllerTest#test_should_not_update_status_if_nothing_has_changed:
   ActionController::ParameterMissing: param is missing or the value is empty: status
   app/controllers/statuses_controller.rb:80:in `status_params'
   app/controllers/statuses_controller.rb:51:in `block in update'
   app/controllers/statuses_controller.rb:50:in `update'
   test/controllers/statuses_controller_test.rb:83:in `block in <class:StatusesControllerTest>'
```

When I issue a puts statement, the output shows:
    {"status"=>{"content"=>"MyText"}

So I assume the parameter exists and is populated. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, as I am at my wits end. Here is a link to my github where the code is hosted:

http://www.github.com/sean-perryman/treebook

Comment: How do you set `@status` in test case?

Comment: `patch :update, id: @status` - here `@status` is `nil`.. But reason need to search for.

Comment: You require `:status` in `status_params` but in your test, you only pass in `:id`.

Comment: Shouldn't `@status = current_user.statuses.find(params[:id])` be setting the status variable? When I add in `puts @status` before the `respond_to` statement, it returns `#<Status:0x007f9b904cc678>`; wouldn't that signify that it is set and populated?

Comment: @ZachKemp I believe that was there from the scaffold generation; I don't think I made any changes to that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your test case `patch :update, id: @status`.

Try this:

`patch :update, {id: @status.id, status: {user_id: @status.user_id, content: 'MyText'}}`

Your controller update method requires your params passed in to be of the above format. An :id key for the status id and a status key that contains the hash of the status params to be updated.

The exception you have is that you did not passed in the status params.

Another note, it will be good to put a `params.require(:id)` instead of `params[:id]` since your method depends on it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The problem I am having, while following along with the tutorial video, is that this test is to make sure that nothing happens when you update a status without making any changes to the content. In the video, he shows removing the user_id and the content from that test; then running it and it passing just fine. He (Jason Seifer, Treehouse) is using Rails 3 (I am using Rails 4) and an older version of Ruby; could it have something to do with the change from attr_accessible to strong params? That has been a limiting factor in previous iterations of this app.

Comment: Actually, re-reading your post I see what you did. Very insightful! I hadn't thought about just passing it the same text as was already their; effectively not changing what it is when it is submitted. The test passed, thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean behind changing to params.require(:id) instead of params[:id]?

Comment: @SeanPerryman: Using params.require(:id) will throws an exception if id is nil. This ensures that the id is passed in for all the security and proper functioning of your code.